# Почему после установки ssl цикличный редирект на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Установил ***ssl*** на saygood.ru, сайт нормально работает, но в админку не могу зайти. В конфиге поставил `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` идет цикличный редирект, ставлю `false` загружается, но скрипты, стили не подгружаются. В чем проблема? Как заставить работать правильно https://saygood.ru/wp-admin/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Скрипты и стили отваливаются, потому что обращение к сайту идет через https, а стили и скрипты подгружаются по http, и браузер их блокирует, что логично. Надо указать движку правильный адрес сайта с указанием протокола https в конфиге `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
```

Или в админке, в разделе Параметры → Общие, настроить можно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если пути к файлам не указаны вместе с протоколом http явно в шаблоне, то все будет работать. Можно [здесь](https://wpmag.ru/2014/wordpress-https/) подробнее почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Очень может быть что проблема на стороне хостинга. И решать ее надо там же. Но можно использовать костыль - вставить в файл wp-config.php код:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Мне несколько раз помогало. И если поможет и вам, то лучше долбить хостера, чтобы внес изменения в настройки у себя. Почему и какие именно настройки есть в [этой статье](http://forum.ispsystem.ru/showthread.php?30974-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-HTTPS-(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).